# Accidentally overwritten local code with old git commit. Any way to restore?

Tags: git, visual-studio

23 days ago, I have created a git repository and pushed the complete already existing VS project through the VS git extension. Not fully understanding git and its technical phrases(branch, fetch, pull, push, commit, stash, sync), I wanted to sync all my local code with my online repository. However, I accidentally clicked something wrong, exiting VS after I have been unable to sync the project with the online repo.

The next time I opened the project in VS, I realized that all files that existed in the old git commit (from 23 days ago) have overwritten the current files, and all the other ones that didn't exist in that commit are completely lost. I opened the project folder in Windows Explorer but the current files are nowhere to be found. I have tried using file recovery software but with very little luck (recovered only one file).

I am almost certain that there is no way to restore the current files, but since I am really desperate as 23 days of work is no small thing, I have to ask here.

Finally solved the problem, the current project files were stashed but I dropped the stash. I found the hash of the dropped stash and applied it, and got my files back - all by following instructions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Good you found the solution. I would recommend to commit on a daily basis :)

Comment: Also, you should not edit your question to post the solution. You can provide an answer to your own question.